# Copying Charts From One Sheet to Another

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to generate approximately 40 graphs automatically in a preset format. Currently, I copy and paste each of the graphs by hand to a new worksheet, excluding any rows of supporting information that separate them. I've been working with the code below to copy and paste the charts automatically, however, it pastes them in the exact same location as the origin sheet.

Is there any way I could condense the charts so they all paste together? Ideally, they would paste in the same column from the origin sheet, just without any rows separating them.

```
Sub overview1()
    Dim OutSht As Worksheet
    Dim Chart As ChartObject
    Dim PlaceInRange As Range

    Set OutSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview_1") '<~~ Output sheet
    Set PlaceInRange = OutSht.Range("B2:J21")        '<~~ Output location

    'Loop charts
    For Each Chart In Sheets("Summary").ChartObjects
        'Copy/paste charts
        Chart.Copy
        OutSht.Paste PlaceInRange
    Next Chart

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks to Søren Holten Hansen for the code. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190863/copy-charts-from-one-sheet-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub overview1()
    Dim OutSht As Worksheet
    Dim Chart As ChartObject
    Dim PlaceInRange As Range

    Set OutSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview_1") '<~~ Output sheet
    Set PlaceInRange = OutSht.Range("B2:J21")        '<~~ Output location

    'Loop charts
    For Each Chart In Sheets("Summary").ChartObjects
        'Copy/paste charts
        Chart.Copy
        OutSht.Paste PlaceInRange
        'Code below changes the range itself to something 20 rows below
        Set PlaceInRange = PlaceInRange.offset(20,0)
    Next Chart

End Sub
```

Comment: I changed the offset value to 1 and that is slightly better than what I had. However, I want them to maintain their original column. The structure is Years running across the top, with various chart types running down in rows. Each chart is of a specific type for a specific year. My end goal would be to have all the charts for 2018 in the 2018 column, 1 after the other. Then all of the charts for 2019 in the 2019 column, and so on. Is that possible?